Getting rid of cat pee smell
Have baseboard heating and it connects through the wall from one room to the next. Cat peed on tile floor cleaned with enzymatic several times. Still smelled cat pee. As liquids will do they travel downhill and saturated the insulation that was in the wall where the baseboard pipes go through. Now there is cat pee stench coming from the hole. Guessing it’s all on the wood behind the hole. Have been treating with enzymatic cleaner but after several treatments nothing seems to help.
My questions-

Do I just spray some BIN or Bullseye paint in there to help seal the wood?
If I do that will foam spray insulation stick to it?
Is foam spray insulation able to be cleaned by enzymatic solutions? Cause we all know the cat will probably pee there again.
Do I paint the wall with bin on both sides of wall in area of baseboard pipes? Cause of wicking on back side of drywall?
I know it’s a lot. Thanks for any responses. Trying to get as much info so I don’t make a bigger mess than I already have.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My experience is that its very potent and very difficult to get rid off.  I was moving house and put down my PC on the carpet for 5mns, and or Tom sprayed it. I immediately rinsed it several times with baking soda and water.  Despite that, that spot kept corroding forever.  Get your cats neutered.

Start by treating the area with a 1:1 White Vinegar/ water solution, then use the enzyme cleaner. The combination breaks down the Uric acid stench. Perseverance is key. Repeat as necessary. Increase to a Straight vinegar (5% acetic) solution if required. Cleaning Vinegar is 10% acetic acid and may expedite a solution in this confined area. If you have a wet or dry vac, dilute the area with water after the vinegar treatment and use the vac to clean up prior to the enzyme treatment.
Foam insulation sticks to everything. Skinned Foam can be painted with stain blocker. Cut foam will exacerbate the problem because of the cellular nature of the product. Use several coats of stain blocker to create a smooth surface.
Get the cat fixed and/or consult a Veterinarian on diagnosing the cat's stress issues.
